# Web Security - MVC

Tags: .net, security, asp.net-mvc-2, azure

So you always hear a bunch of stories about web sites getting popular, and then getting hacked. Basically, I am releasing (as the sole programmer) a website in a few weeks. It's made with MVC2 and it's going to run on the Azure Cloud.

I just would like to know which types of things are "hackable" so to speak. What types of things can I look out for NOW, so I won't be receiving an e-mail in a month saying, "pay me $1,000 or we will take your site down - Anonymous). Yes, that's common.

Mainly because, I doubt I would even be able to fix what was hacked. I'm a good enough programmer to create a site and get it working, but not experienced enough to deal with these sorts of things.

Thanks!

Comment: "Yes, that's common"? What are you smoking? :)

Comment: I've seen numerous reports of this happening to a lot of popular sites. I read a lot of blog posts :) This happens a lot to dating sites in particular it seems, which mine isn't, but still.

Comment: Oh come on! If there was a definite answer to this question that could fit here do you really think that there would be any hackers left out there? They would have nothing left to hack :-)

Comment: LOL. I just want some pointers that's all. Things to be aware of. Common vulnerabilities, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you watched the [The HaaHa Show: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Security with Haack and Hanselman](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/FT05)? They go through in depth what you should be thinking about and how somebody might atempt to hack your site and what you can do to protect your users.

It's a very entertaining session geard at ASP.NET MVC security specifically.

Comment: Have not, and will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest going through the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project), which is a very good starting point to understand different kind of threats for web security.

Comment: I was going to suggest injection and XSS but these are both covered here. +1

Comment: This is great and I think I have all of these mostly covered. Thanks!